# How to include cspi/spi.h header file in JNI code?

Tags: java, c, linux, java-native-interface

I am trying to include spi.h header file in JNI C code, when the */usr/include/at-spi-1.0/cspi/spi.h* file is included in c code I got the following fatal error like " *fatal error: cspi/spi.h: No such file or directory* ".

for creating '.so' file i used following command like:

```
sudo gcc -shared -fPIC -o libHelloJNI.so -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include  -I/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/include/linux  -I/usr/include/at-spi-1.0/cspi  HelloJNI.c
```

using '-I' I included JNI.h header file successful but when I am trying to include the */usr/include/at-spi-1.0/cspi/spi.h*, file I got the fatal error that *No such file or directory*.

so please look at following code and give your feedback please!

```
#include<jni.h>
#include<cspi/spi.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>
#include"HelloJNI.h" 

// Implementation of native method sayHello() of HelloJNI class
   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_HelloJNI_sayHello(JNIEnv *env, 
                                      jobject thisObj,jint a) 
   {
       printf("Hello World! %d\n",a);
       return;
   }

   JNIEXPORT void JNICALL JAVA_HelloJNI_initSPI(JNIEnv *env, jclass 
                                               cls)
   {

      int init_error;
      init_error = SPI_init();
      putenv("GTK_MODULES=gail:atk-bridge");
      putenv("GNOME_ACCESSIBILITY=1");

      if(init_error)
      {     
               printf("First time error %d in Initialising 
                      SPI\n",init_error);   
      }
      else
      {
                printf("SPI Initialise successfully");
      }
           SPI_event_main();
           return;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify `cspi/spi.h` in the `#include` directive, you don't need `cspi` in the `-I` switch.

Change it to:

```
-I/usr/include/at-spi-1.0/
```

Comment: klas thanks for your reply, I tried your suggestion but I got this error "fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory" but I also include glib.h then also I  got "fatal error: glibconfig.h: No such file or directory"

Comment: Maybe it is better to change the `#include` to `#include <spi.h>` instead of changing the `-I` directive depending on where the `glib.h` include file is located.